# Is it a good idea to place an electric boiler on the warm water line?

Tags: water-heater, faucet, boiler, hot-water

I have a condensing gas boiler (tank-less) at one end of my house. I have a bathroom at the the other end of my house, at a higher level.

In the morning if I open the hot water tap it takes about 15L (~4 gallons) of water, and 60-70 seconds to get hot water because the water line is very long and the cold water needs to be displaced before the actual warm water "arrives". The gas boiler is powerful and produces hot water very fast and very hot. But the cold-water-displacement part is the problem.

Obviously this is annoying and I was thinking to install a (classic) electric boiler (small, 30L / 8 gallons) to use as a buffer MOUNTED ON THE WARM WATER LINE AND NOT ON THE COLD ONE. This would hold a buffer of warm water by using electrical energy. In the morning when I open the hot water tap I would get warm water from the electric boiler which, in turn, would refill from the warm water line which for the first 60-70 seconds would get quite cold water.

This would be, IMO, an acceptable trade-off of space, electric bill etc. in exchange for the convenience of having warm water anytime.

***My CONCERN is if I keep using it after the cold water "finished" and fresh, hot water is fed in the electric boiler, would it hurt it? Or would it hurt me (by serving too hot water) or some other disadvantage that I cannot think of?***

Comment: Think most people go with pipe insulation and a small circulating  pump to keep warm water near where it is needed.

Comment: I have read of the re-circulation method but as far as I could understand this would not work with a tank-less boiler...

Comment: I have a Navian on demand HW heater and it does support re-circ. But the OP should weigh the costs of keeping a hot water supply up to temp constantly vs. the cost of running the water until the hot water "arrives".....there is also the convenience factor to be considered...    who wants to wait for up to a minute to get hot water???  Everything is a tradeoff.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson: Wow, I thought re-circ is not suitable for on-demand/instant/tank-less heaters! On the other hand, it would keep the flame going and consuming potentially lots of gas. Oh, the 60-70 seconds of waiting for the water to reach the faucet (sorry for using "arriving" - English is not my native language) is only the first usage in the morning, the pipes get "primed" and subsequent usages are far more decent from a waiting time point of view.

Comment: @AndreiRînea   The on demand WH w/re-circ does not keep the flame going all the time, it only fires up when the temp in the re-circ line drops to a certain set point, and then only for a minute or two.   But and here's the big BUT, unless the WH re-circ can be put on a timer, like "don't do this a night" it will do this 24/7 and will consume additional fuel.  Re-circs are very nice for large houses with spread out bathrooms, etc. but they come with the price of keeping the hot water lines hot all time as well as running the re-circ pump.  Comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Congratulations, we see many very stupid plans to combine tanked and tankless heaters. This is the first that isn't stupid.

Comment: But.... your numbers make no sense. A 3/8" water pipe has 1.57 cc per cm, so would need to be 95m long (over 300') to hold 15 litres.  A 1/2" water pipe is 2.5cc/cm, so 60m (200'). A 3/4" water pipe (foolish choice for a hot water line because of the wait) would be 34m long to contain 15l of water.   A house that big ought to have a satellite hot water system.  Also, purging 15l in 60s means a rather high shower flow (about 4 GPM), very luxurious but also very costly to heat.  Perhaps you can address those things.  A 1.5 GPM (6 l/m) shower is fine. The British electric showers are less.

Comment: @George I could see a re-circ being triggered by a 2 minute timer in the bathroom. Flip the timer as you're getting undressed. It runs for 2 minutes. It's done.  No burdensome 24x7 heating load.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  might work, but only if the on-demand tankless supports remote switches.  A lot depends upon the exact model of the tankless  If there is a separate re-circ  pump that could be wired to a switch it could work.  In my case it's built into the Navian unit so that's a no-go for a timer.  It's in a vacation home so I simply turn the on-demand WH off when I'm not there.

Answer (score 6):

Point of use water heaters are a common solution to the problem you are trying to solve. Most operate on 120 Volt and can plug into a standard outlet and take about 12 amps. You can set the temperature a degree or two lower on it so when the water from the main heater gets to it, the smaller unit will turn off. This will not hurt your smaller unit. Just a safety note, both heaters should be set so the water won't seriously burn you.

Comment: that is a good idea, I would set the main heater to 104F (40C) degres and the small electric one to 107F (42C)!

Comment: Thanks @George Anderson

Comment: @Andrei Setting a storage heater at much less than 60C (140F) is a plan to breed very nasty bacteria that will send you to the hospital.  This was exposed after Flint, Michigan made changes to their water supply and had a rash of these cases at once. This has been happening all along, but as random isolated incidents, so a pattern was never observed until Flint.   *Of course this advice contradicts "don't use scalding temperatures", and the cure for that is a thermostatic mixing valve.*

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It seems what happened in Flint was much more complicated than people not heating their water hot enough. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5353852/  If it weren't for all the other problems there would have been enough chlorine in the water to avoid the bacterical contamination https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5828617/

Comment: @DDuck Well that would be great if your goal was to rationalize away any need to deal with the issue.  "Just don't live in Flint! Solved!"  But I would follow the advice of my national health department, I think.

Comment: In most locations the water wasted waiting for hot water for a shower could be considered negligible compared to the amount used for the shower. The lavatory is different. Often only a small amount of water is to be dispensed and it is relatively wasteful to dump 5 or 10 times the amount of water one needs to get to warm water. In this case a 120 V point-of-use tankless WH or very small tank would remedy this. The most efficient way to do this would be to plumb the lavatory with cold water only and divert some of the cold through a point-of-use WH.

Comment: Generally there is not a 120 V receptacle under the bathroom lavatory so installing an electric point of use WH in a bathroom would require installing that. We have a gas fired tankless central WH and I don't like the thought of the waste water and wear on the WH in dispensing small amounts of hot or warm water from the lavatory. For shaving I put a pint of warm water in a small pitcher. I use the cold water to wash the razor. I fill the pitcher with warm water from the shower at the end of my shower. When I am shaving without showering I warm water on the stove and take it into the bathroom.

Comment: To wash your face decant some hot water from an electric kettle into a bowl with some cold water in it and you have warm water without having to cycle your central gas fired water heater. For washing dishes I do not use hot water from the tap. (We do not have a dishwasher.) Next to the kitchen sink I have an 1800 W standalone induction heater and a 4 L kettle. We use our Bosch central tankless WH for showering and clothes washing. At the bathroom lavatory we dispense only cold water. We have not placed a small electric kettle in either bathroom, but this is always an option.

Comment: @JimStewart  Do you take a horse drawn wagon into town to go shopping?  :-) .....  i thought I was the only one without a dishwasher...

Comment: At a formative age I was in the Peace Corps in Fiji. Our quarters had cold running water, but not not a water heater. Cold showers were fine for most of the year but not winter. In winter we took a 4 L kettle of boiling water into the shower stall and mixed it with cold water in a bucket. Poured warm water over ourselves with a metal cup.

Answer (score 6):

First, I would *actually measure* your numbers. Because I find 15l of water *in the pipe* to be non-believable.  That's 100m (300'+) if the pipe is 3/8" trade size, 60m (200') if 1/2" pipe, and 35m (100+') of 3/4" pipe, but 3/4" would be a dumb choice because it has a huge inventory of water, which means a ridiculous wait for hot water.

If your house really is that big, a single water heater for the whole house is impracticable.

### Your tank needs to be pretty big, though.

Here's the thing.  As your tank refills, it's going to be filling with *cold* water. **Hot water tanks are specifically designed to separate flow**.  So for the first 2/3 (20 lit34s) of water, you'll take that off the top of the tank and it'll be tank temperature.  But with only 10 liters of old water left, what's in the tank? 15 liters of cold water from the pipe, and 5 liters of actually hot water that has finally made it through.  Let's say the pipe lives at 10C and you want the water at 40C.  Half the water in the tank will be 40C, and the other half 10C, *now mixed together* because the separation is no longer working.  What temperature will that water be?  That's right, 25C. Barely tepid.

And it will be like that for the next 20 liters of usage. Then for the following 30 litres or so, it will slowly blend to warm up bit by bit.

This will result in an annoying "mid-shower cold lump" that will probably just motivate you to take Navy showers lol.

But let's do it again with a 120 liter tank.  Now your first 80 liters are fine, and the first 15 liters of cold water will have plenty of time to diffuse into the last 40 liters remaining.

### Temperature will also help.

You seem to want to run the hot water system at very close to desired final shower temperature.  That is dumb. You want to mix significantly hotter water with cold water, so you have some headroom for variances in hot water temperature.  (This might be a big part of why you need to run 15 liters of water to be comfortable).

Ideally, you want an automatic mixing valve, which will automatically adjust out these hot water temp variances, and also provide anti-scald protection.  Anti-scald protection in turn allows you to run the tank hotter still, which further stabilizes spigot temperature.

But much more importantly, hotter tank water allows the tank to stop dangerous bacteria growth - a phenomenon only recently understood, because fatalities from it happened sporadically and randomly.  When Flint, Michigan made abrupt changes to their water supply, among other things it triggered a large enough cluster of cases to become detectable! Investigation ensued and found low-temperature water tanks festooned with legionella and other bacteria. Before that, no one knew!

Now if you don't want a clunky "hotel style" valve, I hear you. They make much better thermostatic mixing valves which allow 2-dimensional control of flow and temperature - like a joystick. Sometimes flow is an ungainly push/pull, but temp is a fine control knob that can be simply left in the desired position.

But if you really like two valves, thermostatic mixing valves can be plumbed in *right before* the hot water tap.  This will mix in cold water as necessary to keep the the hot water tap right on target temperature. (and prevent scalding, of course).

Comment: The pipe is 1 inch in diameter. Even thicker than the 3/4 you mentioned..

Comment: Outer diameter, that is.. Polypropylene : https://www.leroymerlin.ro/produse/teava/662/teava-ppr-alba-cu-insertie-de-fibra-compozita-25-x-3.5-mm-l-4-m/1556

Comment: As for pipe distance between WH and faucet it is about 25-30m indeed.

Comment: @AndreiRînea That seems roughly equivalent to 3/4" NPT, so yeah. Obviously someone thought bigger pipes were more deluxe... true on cold, but hot causes this.

Comment: @Harper according to the instruction manual of my Bosch tankless WH operating it at a relatively low output temperature reduces the formation of boiler scale in the heat exchanger. It makes sense to operate the WH at the lowest temperature that will meet the demand. We set the gas flow to the burner to the lowest that will provide hot enough water for showering. So at the shower 90 % of the water is from the hot line and 10 % from the cold line. This means that the water at the kitchen sink is not hot enough to kill bacteria on flatware so we mix in scalding water from a kettle.

Comment: @Andrei someone wanted an upscale house in our neighborhood of 1970 built tract houses on 10,000 ft^2 lots. They demolished a 2000 ft^2 single story house and built a modern 3000 ft^2 2-story first quality custom house. For hot water they installed TWO first quality tankless water heaters on separate branches each I think about 180 kBTU / h. I think the conversion factor makes each WH about 50 kW so they have a total water heating capacity of 100 kW.  I suppose they don't have to wait long for hot water to arrive at a point of use.

Comment: @Andrei what country is this house in?

Comment: @Andrei is your water piping polypropylene or is it PEX? (PEX is polyethylene cross linked.) Do you know what is the recommended upper temperature limit for your house piping?

Comment: @JimStewart that makes sense for tankless.  For tanked, you have to address the elephant in the room, or rather, the bacteria in the tank. I agree 170k BTU/hr = 50 kW = 205 amps or so.  So they're talking over 400A just for that if they're doing it electric.  I would've gone for a 12 kW heater per bathroom myself, so you can lean more into load diversity.

Comment: Modern gas fired tankless water heaters have electronic controls that vary the gas flow to achieve a set output water temperature as the flow rate varies. Our primitive Bosch has no electronic controls. The gas flow is varied by a valve operated by a slider on the front. I am sure the OP's WH has electronic controls.

Comment: @JimStewart: The house is in Romania (see my profile). The water piping is Polypropylene (which is rated for -10..+95 Celsius / 14..203 Fahrenheit). I wish it was copper but I've bought the house already built..

Comment: We have had pinhole leaks in some of our 50 year old copper tubing; copper is definitely not perfect. I do not hear of polypropylene being used here in the US currently. Polybutylene was used at one time, but it had some failures. The least expensive piping used here now is PEX although some expensive builds do use copper. In some cheaper builds in the medium past PVC and CPVC were used for water distribution piping. Is your building a slab on grade, a basement, or a crawl space? Are the hot water lines (from water heater to point of use) in soil contact or in air under floors or in walls?

Comment: I believe the building is 'slab on grade' or close to that. I have little idea on how the hot water lines traverse the floor horizontally, I only found out vertical sections of the hot/cold pipes which have vents and visiting (small) doors. I do not think the pipes are in contact with the soil or slab.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to run the hot water supply as a "loop" and each faucet is a small tee off the loop.

Then a small pump that drives the flow from and back to the tank will have water to each faucet quickly.

This is done in larger houses and buildings due to the waste of water that you describe.

Comment: my boiler does not have a tank, it is a tank-less boiler

Comment: @JimStewart: Immergas Victrix Tera 38 kW. Here's a general presentation: https://www.immergas.com/en/product?title=VICTRIX%20TERA%2038%201 and here's the user/installer manual: https://www.immergas.com/imp/0106G/Victrix-Tera-28-1_32-1-38-1-1040295_007.pdf

Comment: Water isn't metered, it's from a well..

Comment: @JimStewart I don't have any problem washing my face.

Comment: @JimStewart just wondered how your rant has anything to do with my answer?

Comment: @JimStewart then comment on the OP's post, which is at the top normally, not on my answer.